# disabling print screen option for chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i want to disable print screen option for chrome,i have code working fine for IE but not for chrome.
help me out in this

Comment: What's the code you have so far?

Comment: Impossible. Click on the taskbar and it will no longer work in IE.

Comment: agree as long as the browser is active you will do some tricks to avoid getting print screens. But David is right.

Comment: Even if you could stop the browser, how do you stop 3rd party apps from doing screen captures?

Comment: Printscreen key can not be captured by keyboard event, it works as system key,  In IE you can clear clipboard to clear what you have taken as SNAP, but in chrome you can clear clip board